# Re-writing SQL query to use Group By

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a practice task of `Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:`

I provided the following solution:

```
SELECT w1.continent, w1.name, w1.area
  FROM world w1
WHERE w1.area = (SELECT MAX(area)
                            FROM world w2
                          WHERE w2.continent = w1.continent)
```

That makes perfect sense and is correct. However, it seems more natural to use a `GROUP BY` here. That is, `GROUP BY continents` and pick out the country which has the maximum area.

Does someone know how to do this? I am having trouble converting my correlated sub-query to a group by.

Comment: You would actually use a group by and an order by. Order by area and take the top record using the TOP in MSSQL or LIMIT in MySQL or Oracles ROWNUM command.

Comment: Hm - could you show me how its done to make this concrete?

Answer (score 0):

To get the max area per continent, you would use something like this.

```
SELECT w1.continent, MAX(w1.area)
FROM world w1
GROUP BY w1.continent
```

This is not exactly same as your query as this does not get the corresponding `w1.name` because a `GROUP BY` needs all `SELECT` columns in either `GROUP BY` or in an aggregate function. Since we don't want to aggregate or group by on name, for that we can use a `JOIN` or use `ROW_NUMBER` like this

**JOIN**

```
SELECT w2.continent,w2.area,w2.name FROM
world w1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT w1.continent, MAX(w1.area) as area
    FROM world w1
    GROUP BY w1.continent
)w1
ON w1.continent = w2.continent
AND w1.area = w2.area
```

Problem with join query is that if 2 country have same max area in same continent, then row will be repeated for the continent

**ROW_NUMBER**

```
SELECT w2.continent,w2.area,w2.name
FROM
(
SELECT w2.continent,w2.area,w2.name,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY w2.continent ORDER BY w2.area DESC)as area_number 
FROM world w2
)w2
WHERE area_number = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to use `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: The join query uses `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'm trying to optimize for conciseness

Comment: you should optimize for performance not conciseness. sub query is pretty concise and self explanatory unless you consider the use of `row_number`

Comment: You are right. Both performance and concieness are things I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT w1.continent, w1.name, w1.area, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                        (PARTITION BY w1.continent order by w1.area DESC) 
                        AS rownum 
                        FROM world w1 )
SELECT continent, name, area
FROM CTE WHERE rownum=1
```

Make sure you use a semicolon (;) before WITH statement when using with other sql statements.